# Shopify Increase and decrease product 2 by 2

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid, shopify-liquid

I would like that on my shopify product page, the quantity selector adds 2 by 2 or decreases 2 by 2 the quantity sent in the cart.
The starting quantity must also be 2.
All that I succeeded, but where I block, it is that when we have already clicked on "+" and that we go down to 2, we can still click on "-" which makes us fall to 1 and it distorts everything...
How could I make that on the quantity 2 one can no longer click on the "-"?

Thank you very much for your help here is my current code:

```
                {% if product.tags contains 'Liquidation' and product.type contains 'Chaise' %}
                 
<div class="ProductForm__QuantitySelector" {{ block.shopify_attributes }}>
  {% if block.settings.show_label %}
    <span class="ProductForm__Label">{{ 'product.form.quantity' | t }}:</span>
  {% endif %}

  <div class="QuantitySelector QuantitySelector--large">
  <button type="button" class="QuantitySelector__Button Link Link--secondary" data-action="decrease-quantity" disabled>{% render 'icon' with 'minus' %}</button>
  <input type="text" id="quantity-input" class="QuantitySelector__CurrentQuantity" pattern="[0-9]*" name="quantity" value="2" aria-label="{{ 'product.form.quantity' | t }}">
  <button type="button" class="QuantitySelector__Button Link Link--secondary" data-action="increase-quantity">{% render 'icon' with 'plus' %}</button>
</div>

</div>

<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const decreaseButton = document.querySelector('[data-action="decrease-quantity"]');
  const increaseButton = document.querySelector('[data-action="increase-quantity"]');
  const quantityInput = document.getElementById('quantity-input');

  const updateDecreaseButtonState = () => {
    decreaseButton.disabled = parseInt(quantityInput.value) === 2;
  };

  // Mise à jour initiale de l'état du bouton de diminution
  updateDecreaseButtonState();

  decreaseButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    let quantity = parseInt(quantityInput.value);
    if (quantity > 2) {
      quantity -= 1;
      quantityInput.value = quantity;
    } else {
      quantity -= 0;
      quantityInput.value = quantity;
    }
    updateDecreaseButtonState();
  });

  increaseButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    let quantity = parseInt(quantityInput.value);
    quantity += 1;
    quantityInput.value = quantity;
    updateDecreaseButtonState();
  });

  quantityInput.addEventListener('change', function() {
    let quantity = parseInt(this.value);
    if (isNaN(quantity) || quantity < 2) {
      this.value = 2;
    } else if (quantity % 2 !== 0) {
      this.value = quantity + (2 - quantity % 2);
    }
    updateDecreaseButtonState();
  });
});



</script>

                    {% else %}
                  
                  <div class="ProductForm__QuantitySelector" {{ block.shopify_attributes }}>
                    {% if block.settings.show_label %}
                      <span class="ProductForm__Label">{{ 'product.form.quantity' | t }}:</span>
                    {% endif %}
                    
                  <div class="QuantitySelector QuantitySelector--large">
                      {% assign quantity_minus_one = line_item.quantity | minus: 1 %}
                      <button type="button" class="QuantitySelector__Button Link Link--secondary" data-action="decrease-quantity">{% render 'icon' with 'minus' %}</button>
                      <input type="text" class="QuantitySelector__CurrentQuantity" pattern="[0-9]*" name="quantity" value="1" aria-label="{{ 'product.form.quantity' | t }}">
                      <button type="button" class="QuantitySelector__Button Link Link--secondary" data-action="increase-quantity">{% render 'icon' with 'plus' %}</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
        {% endif %}
```

Comment: You say you want to increment or decrement by 2 each time, so why is it `quantity -= 1;` and `quantity += 1;` in your code then?

Comment: because in this line I start with quantity 2: <input type="text" id="quantity-input" class="QuantitySelector__CurrentQuantity" pattern="[0-9]*" name="quantity" value="2" aria-label="{{ 'product.form.quantity' | t }}"> And if I Begin with quantity 1 and I add 2 by 2, I start with 1...

Comment: Can't make sense of what you are saying. You want to increment / decrement in steps of 2 only, that is what you are asking, no? When the field already contained `4`, and you click the increment button, you want it to show `6` then after - no?

Comment: in fact when we arrive on the product sheet, I want the quantity to be already 2, then by pressing "+" we get 4 then 6... and by pressing "-" if we are on 2 we stay on 2 if we are on 4 we get 2...

Comment: _Everything_ you just talked about, is increments or decrements by 2. So, again, why am I seeing `+= 1` and `-= 1` in your code then?

Comment: Because if I put 2, since the initial value is 2, I get 5, 8, 11 etc... it increases by 3... it’s a real headache because I don’t know why...

Comment: Probably because there _are_ already click handlers in place for these buttons, which implement the +1 / -1 functionality. And you have now added your own, _additional_ click handlers, which manipulate a value, that at this time the original click handlers have _already_ changed ...

Comment: To _remove_ existing event handlers, you would need the reference to the original function that was added in the first place - and if that part of the functionality comes out of Shopify's own scripts, you likely won't have access to that. Would probably make the most sense then, if you replaced the existing buttons with your own (resp. removed whatever Shopify currently uses to select those elements to bind its click handler to - guessing that will either be the `QuantitySelector__Button` class, or the `data-action` attribute value.)

Comment: Ok so from 0 on these buttons, thank you, I will try this approach

Answer (score 0):

Well, finally, I did otherwise, I chose not to make the shopping cart button clickable in case of odd numbers and to leave it clickable if it is even. Moreover I made display run message in case of odd number, here is my solution for those interested.

```
{% comment %}----------------------Check if the product is a chair otherwise we do normally----------------{% endcomment %}
                
                {% if product.tags contains 'Liquidation' and product.type contains 'Chaise' %}
                  
{% comment %}----------------------END Check if the product is a chair otherwise we do normally----------------{% endcomment %}

                  <p style="color: red;" id="messageAlert"></p>
                  <button type="submit" data-use-primary-button="{% if use_primary_button %}true{% else %}false{% endif %}" class="ProductForm__AddToCart ButtonCustom {% if product.selected_or_first_available_variant.available and use_primary_button %}CustomButtonAddToCart{% else %}Button--secondary{% endif %} Button--full" {% if product.selected_or_first_available_variant.available %}data-action="add-to-cart"{% else %}disabled="disabled"{% endif %}>
                      {% if product.selected_or_first_available_variant.available %}
                        <span>{% if product.template_suffix == 'pre-order' %}{{ 'product.form.pre_order' | t }}{% else %}{{ 'product.form.add_to_cart' | t }}{% endif %}</span>

                        {% if block.settings.show_price_in_button %}
                          <span class="Button__SeparatorDot"></span>
                          <span>{{ product.selected_or_first_available_variant.price | money }}</span>
                        {% endif %}
                      {% else %}
                        {{ 'product.form.sold_out' | t }}
                      {% endif %}
                    </button>

                    
{% comment %}----------------------JS to check that the chairs are selling well by pairs otherwise it deactivates the buy button----------------{% endcomment %}
                  <script>
                    
                      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
                        const decreaseButton = document.querySelector('[data-action="decrease-quantity"]');
                        const increaseButton = document.querySelector('[data-action="increase-quantity"]');
                        const quantityInput = document.querySelector('.QuantitySelector__CurrentQuantity');
                        const addToCartButton = document.querySelector('[data-action="add-to-cart"]');
                      
                        const updateAddToCartButtonState = () => {
                          let selectedQuantity = parseInt(quantityInput.value);
                          // Désactive le bouton si la quantité n'est pas un nombre pair
                          addToCartButton.disabled = selectedQuantity % 2 !== 0;
                         // Affiche le message si la quantité est impaire
                          if (selectedQuantity % 2 !== 0) {
                            document.getElementById("messageAlert").textContent = "La quantité doit être un nombre pair.";
                            document.getElementById("messageAlert").style.visibility = "visible";
                          } else {
                            document.getElementById("messageAlert").style.visibility = "collapse";
                          }
                        };
                      
                        // Initialisation
                        updateAddToCartButtonState();
                      
                        // Écouteurs d'événements pour les boutons
                        decreaseButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
                          setTimeout(function() {
                            updateAddToCartButtonState();
                          }, 10);
                        });
                      
                        increaseButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
                          setTimeout(function() {
                            updateAddToCartButtonState();
                          }, 10);
                        });
                      
                        // Écouteur d'événements pour les changements manuels dans l'input
                        quantityInput.addEventListener('change', updateAddToCartButtonState);
                      });
                  </script>
{% comment %}----------------------END JS to check that the chairs are selling well by pairs otherwise it deactivates the buy button----------------{% endcomment %}
```